# How to find/remove an element of vector of struct with specific parameter?

Tags: c++, c++98

I have a struct of slotAndId struct, which is declared like so

```
typedef struct {      
    int slot;
    int id;
} slotAndId;
```

Then I have a vector which holds many objects of type slotAndId...

```
slotAndId object;
vector<slotAndId> ids;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    object.slot = i;
    object.id = i + 2000;   //random id as example, this will be generated by something else in reality.
    ids.push_back(object);
}
```

If I then wanted to find, for example, if there's a slotAndId object which has slot equal to 20 within the vector, how would I do that in C++98? How would I then be able to delete that specific slotAndId object from the vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is for.

```
bool HasSlot20(const slotAndId& item)
{
    return item.slot == 20;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<slotAndId> ids = {..};
    std::vector<slotAndId>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(
       ids.begin(),
       ids.end(),
       HasSlot20
    );
}
```

We need the extra function because C++98 doesn't have lambdas, but we can make it more flexible by using a functor instead:

```
struct HasSlot
{
   HasSlot(const int id) : m_id(id) {}

   bool operator()(const slotAndId& item)
   {
      return item.slot == m_id;
   }

private:
   const int m_id;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<slotAndId> ids = {..};
    std::vector<slotAndId>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(
       ids.begin(),
       ids.end(),
       HasSlot(20)
    );
}
```

or:

```
int main()
{
    HasSlot finder(20);

    std::vector<slotAndId> ids = {..};
    std::vector<slotAndId>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(
       ids.begin(),
       ids.end(),
       finder
    );
}
```

Now this logic is re-usable with different parameters.

Alternatively just have a loop!

If your container is very large, you might consider a different (or additional) data structure that can do this in better than linear time.